# Search ipset with settype instead of setname

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ip, iptables

I know the basic functionality of ipset list.
With ipset list, we can get a particular ipset details by providing the setname.

But I want to know if any ipset rule is present in the list of a particular settype. Browsing the whole list would be very tedious.

Do anyone know how to do that. I didn't find any answer even near about answer on internet.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok thanks for redirecting in right direction. I can put up my question on Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

IPSet does not support query with types, but with names.
You can do these:

```
> ipset list -name  

out_tcp_rej_dp  
out_tcp_acc_dp  

> ipset list out_tcp_rej_dp  

Name: out_udp_rej_dp  
Type: bitmap:port  
Header: range 1-65535   
Size in memory: 8304  
References
```